# How can i get specifc data after a specific pattern using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following data:

```
policy output MRSUU_1:6-828
```

How can i use regex to search my data which will always be in this format:

```
policy output MRSUU_(digit)(colon)(digit)(hyphen)828
```

I want to be able to search my data as above but get me anything after hyphen.. so my search would always look for the string policy output `MRSUU_` and then a digit, colon, digit, hyphen and then return me whatever is after...

```
output answer wanted : 828
```

Comment: If theres only one hyphen in the whole string just split the string at `'-'` and get the last item of the array, (in this case `[1]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import re

text = "policy output MRSUU_1:6-828"
res = re.search(r"MRSUU_\d+:\d-(\d+)", text)
res.groups()
```

output:

```
('828',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a couple of really simple tools (prefix check and split) will work just as well as one complex tool (regex). Which approach is better will depend on the nature of your input data and how robust your code needs to be, but my hard-earned parsing advice is prefer simpler techniques until you are certain that they won't work.

```
lines = [
    'foo',
    'policy output MRSUU_1:6-828',
    'bar',
]

PREFIX = 'policy output MRSUU_'

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(PREFIX):
        n = line.split('-')[-1]
        print(n)
```